# title and navigation bar - css problems (gaps)

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble making my `<h1>` title link for my page expand to fill the whole `<header>` tag in my webpage. There seems to be a gap beneath and I don't know how to fix it.

Also having similar problems with my navigation bar where it continually expands as I increase the size of the browser.

Try mousing over the title and the navigation bar in this JSFiddle to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/8qLkc/

Can someone help me out on how to fix this.

Comment: I'm working on Google Chrome for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the very simple CSS code:

```
header h1 {
    height:100%;
}
```

That expands the `<h1>` to the full height of its parent, which is the `<header>` in this case.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8qLkc/1/)

To fix the problem with the navigation collapsing when resizing the window, use this:

```
nav {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#mainContent {
    clear:both;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8qLkc/2/)

That prevents the navigation links from collapsing when their text exceeds the width of their container, and it makes sure the main content gets its space before it shows the floating elements.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you have any advice about the navigation bar?  The `<nav>` tag continually expands when I increase the browser window beyond a certain point.  I was trying to avoid fixing the height in pixels.